# Apollo headers not found parsing in Node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, apollo

I have the following header configured in my React.js web app, but I don't see them when logging `req.headers` in my Node.js API. The value of `headerData.data` is set in another file, so it's not passing a null parameter.

```
export const headerData = {
  data: null
};

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4300/graphql'
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    ...headers,
    headerData: headerData.data
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the shape of `headerData`? 
Are you trying to create a header called `headerData` here, or what headers do you want to set?

Comment: @phry `headerData` was just an example of type String, but the goal is to pass Auth and ID headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it slightly different, your nesting is wrong:

```js
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "some-new-header": headerValue
    }
  }
})
```